# IBM Blade Center - Power Consumption with SNMP & IPMI

Tags: snmp, ibm, ipmi, blade-server

We have the need to follow and manage the power consumption of each blade, one by one, from our IBM Blade Center system.

Is there a way to do this ?
Anyhow it’s a licensing upgrade or external/internal module to add on the blade system.

Those informations have to be readable by SNMP or IPMI.

many thanks !

Comment: SNMP MIB in chassis .1.3.6.1.4.1.2.3.51.2.2.10.3.1.1.7.$OID